# Converter hora obtida pelo banco de dados de ("Y-m-d H:i:s"); para ("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Neste caso como eu consigo converter sem usar o método

> DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s') no SELECT

```
 <?php                                            
    $resul_ult_aces = "SELECT as data_acesso FROM adms_ultimos_acessos
    WHERE adms_usuario_id = '".$row_user['id']."'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_ult_aces = mysqli_query($conn, $resul_ult_aces);
    $row_ult_aces = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_ult_aces);

    $data_atual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data_ult_aces = $row_ult_aces['data_acesso'];
    $ob_data_atual = new DateTime($data_atual);
    $ob_data_ult_aces = new DateTime($data_ult_aces); 

    $intervalo = $ob_data_atual->diff($ob_data_ult_aces);
    ?>
```

Comment: você quer editar a $data_atual ou a $data_ult_aces?

Comment: ambas para que eu possa resolver um erro, aliás tentar ver se é por isso.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão a função date do PHP espera que os parâmetros para Dia, Mês e Ano sejam separadas por '-' e os parâmetros de Hora, Minuto e Segundos por ':'.

Para converter ao formato que você deseja, você pode converter o date obtido pela função para um string e utilizar a função str_replace do PHP para substituir os ':' por '-'.

Mas acredito que estas conversões irão dificultar a comparação entre datas.

Comment: Então, eu tentei usando str_replace mais não deu certo

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico sobre o que deu de errado?